# Google geocode API gives wrong coordinates for a specific city

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I'm using google API to get longitude and latitude of cities for my application. My application is a Sweden based app and there is a city named "Trosa". Every time I try to get the coordinates of this city it returns me wrong details.

Is this a known issue?

Please see the attached image for postman request.

[image: Postman request]

Comment: Add the country to the request: "Trosa, Sweden" (or you could add viewport or region biasing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the country to the request: "Trosa, Sweden" (or you could add viewport or region biasing).

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Trosa,%20Sweden